# Parsing XML using C#, getting attribute value

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

I have the following (simplified) notepad file, which from what I understand is XML text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <appSettings>
        <add key="Active_01" value="1">
        </add>
  </appSettings>
```

I am trying to parse it using C#.

So far I have the following:

```
public class RFIDScanner
{
    public void GetScannerConfigFile()
    {
        string File = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RFIDScannerConfiguration"];

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(File);

        XmlNode node = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/appSettings");

        String nodename = node.Name;

    }
}
```

So far I know this is all correct, as:

```
nodename = appSettings
```

Which is as it should be.

My problem is, how do I retrieve the value "1" from the field "Active_01".

I now know that the node "add" is a child of the node "appSettings", and a trying to work out how to get the value stored in it.

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer but personally I find XDocument/XNode a lot easier, and more readable code, to understand than the XmlDocument method.

Comment: It looks to me your are trying to reinvent the wheel by using custom code to read config xml files?

Comment: @Steven can you point me towards a more conventional method for achieving my aim?

Comment: @user2970105 It looks to me you are trying to read a standard config file (app.config in the root of your project)? If so, try ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Active_01"]

Comment: @Steven thank you for the suggestion, but it is not a standard config file

Comment: Maybe this approach? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14465/Specify-a-Configuration-File-at-Runtime-for-a-C-Co You could even define your own "scannerSettings" in the config file

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, one is to use the XPath using the function you use above:

```
var value = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/appSettings/add/@value");
```

Another option is to use [xml serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

You'd define classes as follows:

```
public class add
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string key;
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int value;
}

public class appSettings
{
    public add add;
}
```

And then deserialize as follows:

```
var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(appSettings));
var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(s));
appSettings settings = (appSettings) ser.Deserialize(xmlReader);
xmlReader.Close();
```

You can then get the values from `settings`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you wish to parse the '1' from the key `Active_01`, or get the `1` from the value. In Any case, you can use the following code:

```
    public void GetScannerConfigFile()
    {
        string File = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RFIDScannerConfiguration"];

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(File);

        var yourFile = doc.DocumentElement;
        if (yourFile == null) return;

        // Here you'll get the attribute key: key = Active_01 - which can be simply parsed for getting only the "1"
        string key = yourFile.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["key"].Value;

        // Here you'll get the number "1" from the value attribute.
        string value = yourFile.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["value"].Value;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used this way in my code to add values to xml
may be it will help

```
var surveyTypeList = new XElement("SurveyTypes");
            foreach (var item in modelData.SurveyTypeList)
            {
                if (item.IsSelected)
                {
                    var surveyType = new XElement("SurveyType");
                    var id = new XElement("Id");
                    id.Add(item.Value);
                  //  **var i= id.Value**
                    surveyType.Add(id);
                    surveyTypeList.Add(surveyType);
                }
            }
```

you can get value by  var i= id.Value in your code;